# Store values with UserDefaults not working

Tags: swift, swiftui

It doesn't seem to store the values, even though it's connected and runs, this is the code:

**File 1**

```
struct ContentView: View {

@ObservedObject var eatTracker = TimeToEatTrackerViewModel()

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 30) {
        Button(action: {
            self.eatTracker.currentMeal += 1
            print(String(self.eatTracker.currentMeal))
        }){
            Text("Who's next?")
        }

    }
}
}
```

**File 2**

```
class TimeToEatTrackerViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var currentMeal: Int = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "CurrentMeal") {
    didSet {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.currentMeal, forKey: "CurrentMeal")
    }
}

}
```

If I do it on the same file with `@State` it works, but like this is not working for me, why?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
self.eatTracker.currentMeal = self.eatTracker.currentMeal + 1
```

instead of:

```
 self.eatTracker.currentMeal += 1
```